# How to put a main title of the subplots on plt.subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, figure

I used matplotlib.pyplot to plot a list of images `[img1, img2, ..., img100]`, in order to draw them in order, I used `plt.subplots` to divide the figure area.
This is my code:

```py
def show_images(imgs, num_rows, num_cols, titles=None, scale=2, imgText=None, save=False, img_dir=None):  
    figsize = (num_cols * scale, num_rows * (scale))
    _, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, figsize=figsize,frameon =False)
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for i, (ax, img) in enumerate(zip(axes, imgs)):
        img=np.transpose(img * 255, (1, 2, 0))
        ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
        ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        if not titles is None:
            ax.set_title(titles[i])
    plt.show()
    return axes
```

The resulting figure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWAmG.png).
But I wasn't able to put a main title on the plt.subplots figure.
How can I achive that so that it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jepNM.png)?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `plt.figtext(0.5, 0.95, 'myTitle', ha='center')` ?

Comment: fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('this is the figure title')

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just titling the plot itself?

```
plt.title("Your title here")
```

My recollection is that if you do this before you call subplot, it'll title the whole thing.

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't make sense...5555555....